# Blocking specfix URIs with Apache redirect rules

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd

I want to block URL with below pattern

```
   172.31.X.X "172.31.X.X" - - [19/Apr/2019:06:33:56 +1000] "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1555619633.5413479804992675781250 HTTP/1.1" 302 274 "http://www.example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1555619633.5413479804992675781250" "WordPress/4.9.5; https://www.example.com.au" 155 "-" "Cookies:-" –
```

I tried the following but does not seem to be working

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=[0-9]+$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` for the query string and you have to escape `.` to match the dot.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

> REQUEST_URI
>        The path component of the requested URI, such
>   as"/index.html".
>   This notably excludes the query string which is available as its 
>                    own variable named QUERY_STRING.

```
RewriteEngine On  

# this matches:
# /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1555619633.5413479804992675781250
# /wp-cRoN.php?DOING_wp_cron=.&foo=bar
# /wp-cron.php?foo=bar&doing_wp_cron=.

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)doing_wp_cron=[0-9\.]+(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/wp-cron.php$ - [NC,F,L]
```